# Dont get all confirmation mails of sales, magento

Tags: email, magento

I have problem with my magento system, 
I dont get mails for all the sales that i have, and all of the customers dont get confirmation mail.
(I get some of the orders, the customers never get).

I tried to change in "Sales email" to separate mail, bcc, mail with the same site admin, nothing change..

when i go to "sales" "orders"  and "send mail" on one of the orders, some thing i got fail, some time "The order email has been sent.", and some time when it success the customer dosent get it.

for SMTP i use "KSV EXTENSIONS"

Hope you have any idea what to do.
Thanks
Matan.

Comment: First of all, if you are missing some emails ask your system admin/developer to check the mail queue on the server. Also, install the extension suggested by Empiro technologies if possible in your scenario..Its free and allows you to log the emails sent from the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension for sending mail. You can use your gmail, yahoo etc. account here.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html